# Icons not showing with Semantic UI

Tags: css, gulp, icons, font-awesome, semantic-ui

I am building Semantic UI with Gulp using [this guide](https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html.)

However, the problem is now that the icons are not showing. So if I use 
`<i class="facebook icon"></i>`, nothing shows up.

I guess I haven't built the icon font or something like that.

Is it necessary to load Font Awesome or something like that myself? I have read through the Semantic UI documentation, but I cannot find anywhere stating that I have to do anything to enable icons.

Comment: have you loaded the semantic.css file?

Comment: Yes I have and everything else in Semantic UI works except for the icons

Comment: Also, make sure you haven't got a font-family override on. That got me and was super annoying ! :-( It tries to render the icons in that font-family, which won't work.

Answer (score 8):

You need to include the font assets which are located in themes/default/assets/fonts/

The *themes* folder must be in the same directory as your semantic.css file.

The fonts are imported externally from the semantic.css file from within the *themes* directory.

To obtain this directory, [download](https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html) the zip for semantic ui and look inside the *dist* folder.

Comment: still cant get what do you mean at the first step, i did a peak to `assets/semantic-ui/components/icon.css` and find out that `src: url("./../themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.eot");` is correctly included yet i find this hard to understand

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue, use this link tag in the head of your html and you're good to go :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" />
```

Got this from their official [website](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/semantic-ui).

Comment: Is there a solution without using a CDN? I need to use this library without using CDNs.

Answer (score 4):

Since it's not marked as ansered yet in 2019...  Here's the clear answer. The above answers are correct as well, just not straight forward.

So basically what you missed out is the inclusion of the icons themselves. When you download semantic-ui it comes with themes folder within the "dist" folder. what you must do is copy that themes folder and paste it in your project folder where your `semantic-ui.css` is located. and it will work.

Please remember to mark the question as answered.

Comment: Bro, you saved me, big time. Took me four hours to figure out this issue, thanks to you!
If you were signed up as a BAT creator, I would send you a tip.

Answer (score 4):

I had an CORS-issue (causing square empty icons) with the Semantic UI Icons when loading the minified CSS from a CDN. Turns out that it was my location override that caused it, turning it off made the icons display properly.

Comment: I had similar issue. Thanks 

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem replacing this line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dist/semantic.min.css">
```

with this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.8.7/dist/semantic.min.css">
```

I also had to add link to icon.min.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fomantic-ui/2.8.7/components/icon.min.css">
```

I wrote a [post](https://javistkamartaslysz.medium.com/fomantic-ui-icons-not-showing-1298cd99f09c) about it on medium :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case I forgot to import the semantic ui css file. Import it in the App.js ( as it is the top level file ) or anywhere inside your project.

`import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solve it adding the following lines on my webpack.mix.js

```
  .copy('node_modules/semantic-ui-css/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff','public/css/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff')
  .copy('node_modules/semantic-ui-css/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff2','public/css/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff2')
  .copy('node_modules/semantic-ui-css/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.ttf','public/css/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.ttf')
```

and then executing the command

> npm run dev

This add in my case the missing files I need

Answer (score 1):

In the `semantic.css` file, you'll find this line:

```css
background: url("./themes/.....")
```

so, what you have to do is to copy the `themes` folder with all its contents beside your `semantic.min.css`

All simply copy the folder `Semantic-UI-CSS-master` with all its contents to your `public/static/wwww` folder, and will get things working smoothly.

Comment: Thank you for sharing "public/static/wwww" you saved my day. :)

Answer (score 0):

I partially fixed this by downloading `icon.min.css` from [this link](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/semantic-ui) and then replacing the CDN link with this two lines:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/icon.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/semantic.min.css"/>
```

There are still some icons missing: all the outlined ones.
You could also try the fonts folder from [this branch](https://github.com/kim366/UI-Icon) but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

So as the other answers have provided you can change the script to look like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" />
```

Stop the server and close your browser. If you do not fully close the browser the error will persist. Restart your server.

If this does not resolve your issue, you can also choose to install the CSS library locally via

`npm install semantic-ui-css`

Then, import the library into your root `index.js` component,

`import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";`

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. However i figured out the issue was in my local index.css file. I was using custom fonts from [fontsource](https://fontsource.org/).

```html
body,
* {
  font-family: "Rubik Variable", sans-serif !important;
}
```

This was overriding the sementic ui fontawsome fonts font family.
Font awsome using  tag to display the icons, we can ignore it from css * selector.

Fix:

```html
body,
*:not(i) {
  font-family: "Rubik Variable", sans-serif !important;
}
```

Semantic includes a complete port of Font Awesome 5.0.8 designed by the FontAwesome for its standard icon set. [Semantic Ui Icons](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/icon/)

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problems using react
tried everything mentioned and nothing worked
then just replaced this link
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css" />`

hope that helps